# jTable removing the decimal place from type currency js

Tags: javascript, jtable, decimal, currency

I'm using `jtable` to display large tables on my webpages. I have quite a few columns which are displaying currency values. They are being displayed with two decimal places and I would like to remove the decimal places. Example: `$ 12356.87 -> $ 12356`

I have tried this and there was no difference in the display

```
defaultTaskFields.price=Math.trunc(defaultTaskFields.price.valueOf());
```

and this didn't work either

```
defaultTaskFields.price=Math.trunc(defaultTaskFields.price);
```

Here's an example of the object that I'm dealing with:

defaultTaskFields = {
    task_id: {
        key: true,
        list: false
    },
    price: {
        title: "Price",
        type: "currency"
    }
};

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Math.floor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)? does what you ask - but is that best for currency? [Math.trunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) is not fully implemented yet

Comment: It didn't work with Math.floor, the "$" sign went away and so did the column heading but the decimal places still remained

Comment: Math.round is probably more appropriate (will return an integer also) in your example would return 12357.

Comment: Math.round didn't work either

Comment: hmm - it sounds like that this is being called after the value is used (try adding `console.log(defaultTaskFields.price)` after your round and see what it returns) - otherwise without a JSFiddle or more code I cant help any further

Comment: I tired `console.log(defaultTaskFields.price)` and I got NaN so I'm thinking that maybe this is stored as a string. What would be the way to manage the decimal removal if it is a string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by converting string to number. jTable stores field values as strings. This is why the Math functions weren't working directly. After conversion it worked out.
From:

```
return "$" + fieldValue;
```

To:

```
return "$" + Number(fieldValue).toFixed();
```

The display went from `$140.56` to `$141`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the end from the string:

```
var desiredEnd = defaultTaskFields.price.indexOf(".");
if(desiredEnd<0){
    desiredEnd = defaultTaskFields.price.length;
}
defaultTaskFields.price = defaultTaskFields.price.substring(0, desiredEnd);
```

This gives the substring between 0 and the first index of ".".
`desiredEnd` checks that "." actually exists and if it doesn't, it just returns the full string.

[substring mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) -
[indexOf mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: I've checked again and `typeof defaultTaskFields.price` is number but when I try to `console.log(defaultTaskFields.price)` I get `NaN`

Comment: in that case the above would work if you add `var dtfPrice = defaultTaskFields.price.toString()` at the top and use that new variable instead of defaultTaskFields.price throughout the following lines. However Javascripts number type is broken by characters such as `$`

Comment: it didn't work. The dollar sign went away but the decimal place and two significant figures are still there.